# custom renderer or conditional styling in handsontable

Tags: css, reactjs, handsontable

Using the official handsontable react wrapper I'm having a hard time figuring out how to register a custom renderer, the goal is to render some rows with a different style. I attempted to write a custom renderer and it was throwing an error saying that the renderer was not registered this could have been because I was trying to register it following the docs https://docs.handsontable.com/0.32.0/demo-conditional-formatting.html where they attach it to Handsontable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function groupingRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, 
cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  td.className = 'group';
}
```

And then to call that function in the settings object that you pass in as a prop to HotTable

```
cells(row, col, prop) {
    const cellProperties = {};
    if((tableData.rows[row]).total) {
      cellProperties.renderer = groupingRenderer;
    }

    return cellProperties;
  },
```

notice im not registering the "renderer" instead I call it directly.

Comment: Is your Handsontable variable the import from the React wrapper---i.e. "import HotTable from 'react-handsontable';"? I'm getting getting TextRenderer is not a property of undefined.

Comment: Ah, I have to install the 'handsontable' package.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I dont see this as a solution.